# Is it ok to use finally at the end of the sentence like this?

Tags: adverb-placement

Is it ok to use finally at the end of the sentence like this?

> I am a teacher finally!

Or do I have to say this?

> I finally am a teacher / I am finally a teacher

You see, most of the people told me that only eventually would be good if used at the end of the sentence, but I am just curious if I can.

Answer (score 1):

From a native speaker, saying finally at the end works just fine and will sound normal spoken in this way. Converting how it would be commonly spoken to written form, you'd write it like this.

> I'm a teacher, finally!

The comma does well to illustrate the emphasis on "finally", which would be expressed with a bit of punch, as if you are relieved to have overcome the significant trials of reaching your end goal.

Answer (score 0):

It should be-->**

> Finally, I'm a teacher now

**-->Like this.. So that it would be sound good, If you use the word "finally" at the end of the sentence or in the middle it'll change the meaning somehow.

Comment: Please [edit] to include an explanation of *why* this is the only correct way; answers without explanation do not teach the patterns of the language well.